# How to solve a stack overflow error in recursive call?

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Task5 {

    private static void stack(int x) {
        if (x == 0) return;
        stack(x - 1);
        if (x % 35 == 0) {
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.print(x + " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        stack(x);
    }
}
```

Any number above 9200 results in a stack overflow error. Is it because a recursive call loops too many times ?

Comment: To avoid the stack overflowing, you need to implement this function differently. Recursion just won't cut it after a while.

Comment: So the recursion if called to many times will eventualy give a stack overflow error ?

Comment: Correct. This is a fundamental problem of recursion that cannot be changed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a StackOverflowError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror)

Comment: Thank you for the answers. It was a homework for me how to avoid the SO error. Have to solve it with standard for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you're encountering an overflow because your recursion stack becomes extremely deep with large inputs. There's no reason this function needs to be recursive, I would suggest implementing an iterative version using loops.